# How to fetch selected value from a dropdownlist in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This may sound simple but i am stuck up at a very strange problem.

I have created dropdown's in my application and i am not able to fetch the selected value On Edit.

Here is my View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Hobbyhome.HobbyHomeAddressList.First().ProvincialState.ProvincialStateID, new SelectList(ViewBag.State, "ProvincialStateID", "ProvincialStateName"), "-----Select State-----", new { @id = "State" })<font color="red">*</font> 
      </div>
```

i have written a function in controller to fetch the value and i am also able to fetch the value but when it goes in View it doesnot show me the value
i have created another dropdown like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Hobbydetail.Hobbymaster.HobbyId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Hobby, "HobbyId", "HobbyName"), "----Select Hobby----", new { @id = "Hobby" })<font color="red">*</font>
```

And the strange thing is i can see the value of the second dropdown but not for first One

What i think is maybe because i am using an **list.First()** in the first dropdown and so it isgiving this problem bcoz On edit view page it only shows me "-----Select State--" as value for first dropdown.

Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "selected value object" in you edit view :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Hobbydetail.Hobbymaster.HobbyId, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Hobby, "HobbyId", "HobbyName", Model.Hobbydetail.Hobbymaster.HobbyId),
    "----Select Hobby----", new { @id = "Hobby" })
```

To have all elements in your DropDown, be sure that your ViewBag.Hobby is initialized and filled in your controller before showing Edit view!

Answer (score 0):

`First()` method returns the first element of a sequence. It will throw you an exception if the source sequence is empty.

**Why you need to use First() there ?** I think you are doing it in the wrong way. your first paramenter of `DropDownListFor` should be a variable which holds the selected value, in this purticular overload you are using.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

> **name** : The name of the form field to return.

You should be using the second approach

I would make a clean ViewModel to handle this. **This makes my Views Clean**.

```
public class AddHobbyViewModel
{
  public int SelectedHobbyId { set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<Hobby> Hobbys { set;get;}
  //other relevant properties for the View.  
}
```

In the GET action method, Instead of returning the data in ViewBag, I would return it in the ViewModel.

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
  AddHobbyViewModel model=new AddHobbyViewModel ();
  model.Hobbys=db.Hobbies();  // get all available hobbies.

  return View(model);
}
```

And in the View,

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => SelectedHobbyId , new SelectList(Hobbys , "HobbyId", "HobbyName"), "----Select Hobby----", new { @id = "Hobby" })
```

Now you will have the selected value available in your httppost mehod in the SelectedHobbyId property

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(AddHobbyViewModel model)
{
  // check model.SelectedHobbyId here
}
```