# Filtering Dropdown list in mvc razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I've two tables

1.Country

- ID
- CountryName

and other table is

2.State

- State ID
- State Name
- Country Id

I am using this code to populate data in dropdownlist of country in `citycontroller.cs`

```
ViewBag.countries = new SelectList(db.Couns.OrderBy(c => c.CountryName).ToList(), "ID", "CountryName");
```

in `create.cshtml`

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Select Country", ViewBag.countries as SelectList)
```

i want the functionality in which the state dropdown should be populated according to the selection of the country dropdown what should be done?????

Comment: Is your country dropdown functioning? I see couple of issues with that.

Comment: @Mohayemin ya its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list of states downloaded already to the client machine then knockout.js would be the way to go.  If you want to download only the states that are related to the selected country once that selection is made you shohuld make an AJAX call to the server when a country is selected and have the success function populate the state list.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `Ajax` calls for that. You may want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11553723/887149) answer I provided to a question similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can wse jQuery ajax to load the States when the country gets selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $("#Country").change(function(){
      var states=""; 
      var countryId=$(this).val();
      $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetStates","Home")/"+countryId,function(data){
           $.each(data,function(index,item){
              states+="<option value='"+item.ID+"'>"+item.StateName+"</option>";
           });
             $("#States").html(states);
      });

    });    
 });    

</script>
```

Assuming `Country` is the ID of your Country DropDown and `States` is the ID of your States Dropdow and you have an action method which accepts the country id as the parameter and get the states in JSON format

```
public ActionResult GetStates(int id)
{
  var stateList=repo.GetStatesForCountry(id);
  return Json(stateList,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming `repo.GetStatesForCountry` returns a List of States based on the country Id passed. You may replace that function call with your method call which returns a list of `State` class objects.

***Suggestion  :*** I would try to avoid the dynamic ViewBag /ViewData approach to populate the Dropdwon and switch to a more strongly typed approach. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500642/how-to-fetch-selected-value-from-a-dropdownlist-in-mvc3/10500817#10500817) is an example how to do it.